# ObjectContext Closed error when using Include?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, objectquery

I am trying to create a generic Get method for Entity Framework, with a dynamic `Where` and `Include`. I am using the code below, however when I try to access a Navigation Property that was in the Include list, I am getting an error about the Object Context being closed

Isn't `.Include()` supposed to load those objects so I don't need to keep the ObjectContext open?

```
public static List<T> GetList<T>(Func<T, bool> where, string[] includes)
    where T : EntityObject
{
    using (var context = new TContext())
    {
        ObjectQuery<T> q = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        foreach (string navProperty in includes)
        {
            q.Include(navProperty);
        }

        return q.Where<T>(where).ToList();
    }
}
```

Code causing error:

```
var x = DAL<MyContext>.GetList<MyEntity>(
                p => p.Id == 1
                , new string[]{ "Type" } );

var y = x.Type;  // Throws an error that context has been closed
```

I feel I must be making some kind of stupid mistake here because I'm new to EF and am still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not re-assigning `q` - this should fix it:

```
    foreach (string navProperty in includes)
    {
        q = q.Include(navProperty);
    }
```

Remember you are using extension methods that each return a **new** `IQueryable<T>`, not modifying the original.

Comment: Oh... >.< I knew it would be something dumb like that, thank you